# Java: No such file or directory when redirecting command line program output to /dev/null

Tags: java

I'm currently working on invoking bash program using java. The bash program output too much message and I want to redirect them to `/dev/null`. But I encountered a weird error `No such file or directory`.

Here is my demo.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Another version I've tried:
            // Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo a > /dev/null");
            ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("echo a");
            // b.redirectOutput(new File("/dev/null")).redirectErrorStream(true);
            b.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to(new File("/dev/null")))
                    .redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = b.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And the error message as follows:

```java
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo a": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 2 more
```

I'm using a `MacBook` with Catalina, and I tried `java 1.8.0_231` and `1.8.0_241` from oracle. (I couldn't use higher java version because one of the dependency of my project requires java 8).

Comment: You are trying to run a program whose name contains the six characters `echo a`.  There is no program whose name consists of those six characters.  `a` is not part of the program name, it’s an *argument* to the program.  Use `new ProcessBuilder("echo", "a")`.

Comment: That's works, thanks. BTW, what about the class `Process`? Should I use `"echo", "a" ,">", "/dev/null"` or ``"echo", "a" ,"> /dev/null"``?

Comment: Neither.  You are already doing it correctly:  use redirectOutput.  If you were to pass `">", "/dev/null"`, they would just be interpreted as more arguments to the echo command, and would not receive any special treatment at all.  They would be the equivalent of the shell command `echo a '>' /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore the output from the process, it's easier and more portable to use `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD` than explicitly redirecting to a special file/device such as /dev/null.

```
        b.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD)
         .redirectErrorStream(true);
```

Forget about using `Runtime.exec` - that method is badly designed and hard to use safely. If you want to do input redirection with the `"> /dev/null"` style, you need to remember that `>` is a construct created by the command interpreter shell, not the operating system, and if you want to use it you must run a shell.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c", "echo a > /dev/null"});
```

Comment: That's a solution since java 9. But one of dependency in my project requires java 8, there is no `DISCARD` in `ProcessBuilder`. The second snippet works in my project, thanks.

Comment: Don't use the second snippet, use your original code. The second snippet is an example of the kind of hoops the old and somewhat broken `Runtime.exec` method forces you to jump.